# Presenting UIDocumentInteractionController in the right place on a UICollectionView using cell.frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a UICollectionView using the standard Flow Layout.  The flow layout presents a collection of documents.

When you tap on one, the UIDocumentInteractionController presents a list of available applications that are capable of handling that document type.  The little arrow from the UIDocumentInteractionController points towards the document that I tapped.  I'm using the reusable cell frame rectangle to identify where the cell is.

Prior to upgrading to iOS7, I believe this worked fine.  Now I'm having an issue in that the UIDocumentInteractionController is not appearing in the correct location.

The code looks like this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:item.templateLink ofType:@"" ]];
docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL
                               usingDelegate:self];
TBTemplateViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TemplateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect rect1 = cell.frame;
bool didShow = [docController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect1 inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

It's as if cell.frame no longer has the same reference point?

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having played around a little longer, it seems that I should be using `presentOptionsMenuFromRect` on `collectionView` rather than `self.view`.  So the code now looks like this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:item.templateLink ofType:@"" ]];
docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL
                           usingDelegate:self];
TBTemplateViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TemplateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect rect1 = cell.frame;
bool didShow = [docController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:rect1 inView:collectionView animated:YES];
```

Does that sound about right?  It seems to have done the trick.  Does anyone know if this would have changed in iOS7, or if I was just perhaps getting away with it before?